# Entity framework 6 many to many insert update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am working on a question/answer software using asp.net mvc, ef6. One of the problems I am trying to solve is insert/update many to many items. For example if a user ask a question and add tags against it, they can either choose the existing tags or create new ones.

My stripped down question class is

```
public class Question
{
    private ICollection<Tag> _tags;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags
    {
        get { return _tags ?? (_tags = new Collection<Tag>()); }
        set { _tags = value; }
    }
}
```

My tag class is like

```cs
public class Tag
{
    private ICollection<Question> _questions;

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions
    {
        get { return _questions?? (_questions=new Collection<Question>()); }
        set { _questions = value; }
    }
}
```

My context is like

```
public class MyDbContext
        : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

When I need to save the question with tags I have to manually check if the tags user has added to the question exist or not. If they don't exist I create them and save the context and then return the tags and add them to the question. I was wondering if there is a better approach for doing something like this in EF6?

My sample code is below

```
public IEnumerable<Tag> CreateOrRetrieveTags(IList<string> tags)
{
    List<string> availableTags = (from t in _context.Tags
        where tags.Contains(t.Text)
        select t.Text).ToList();
    var missingTags = tags.Except(availableTags, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach (string missingTag in missingTags)
    {
        _context.Tags.Add(new Tag
        {
            Text = missingTag
        });
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return from t in _context.Tags
        where tags.Contains(t.Text)
        select t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Include method and letting EF manage the relationship for you.

```js
public void AddOrRemoveTags(IList<string> tags, Question question)
{
   var dbQuestion = _context.Questions.Include(a => a.Tags).SingleOrDefault(a => a.QuestionId == question.QuestionId);
 
   if (dbQuestion != null)
   {
      var remainingTags = new List<string>(tags);
      var tagsToRemove = dbQuestion.Tags.Where(t => !tags.Contains(t.Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
      foreach (var tag in tagsToRemove)
      {
         dbQuestion.Tags.Remove(tag);
         remainingTags.remove(tag.Text);
      }
      foreach(var remainingTag in remainingTags){
         dbQuestion.Tags.Add(new Tag(){ Text = remainingTag });
      }
      _context.SaveChanges();
         
   }
}
```

For new records:

```js
public void AddTags(IList<string> tags, Question question)
{     
  if (question != null)
  {
    var existingTags = _context.Tags.Where(t => tags.ToArray().Contains(t.Text)).ToList()
    var remainingTags = new List<string>(tags);
    foreach (var tag in existingTags)
    {
      question.Tags.Add(tag);
      remainingTags.remove(tag.Text);
    }
    foreach(var remainingTag in remainingTags){
      question.Tags.Add(new Tag(){ Text = remainingTag });
    }

  }
}
```

And then you will need to add your Question object to the context at a higher level.  This should add all of the relevant references and only make a small trip to get the tags that you care about. One important piece is that you don't pull the entire Tags set from the database this way.

Note: If you care about case sensitivity you can .toLower() the entire list and .toLower() the t.Text, this will translate to sql as such.

Comment: Your answer is valid when I need to update a question but the first problem I am trying to solve is when user adds a new question with x number of tags. Having said that it is still far too much code for my liking, could do with some kind of generic way of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

pass complete tags into CreateOrRetrieveTags method then you can filter by Id to identify new tags:

```
public List<Tag> CreateOrRetrieveTags(List<Tag> tags)
{   
    var newTags = tags.Where(t => t.Id == 0);
    foreach (string newTag in newTags)
    {
        _context.Tags.Add(newTag);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return from t in _context.Tags
        where tags.Any(t.Text == t.Text)
        select t;
}
```

Comment: But at that stage I don't have the complete tag. A bit like on Stackoverflow when user is adding tags to question I only have tag string/text.

Comment: @QaiserIftikhar you do not need the complete tag. In case of new tag you can create a tag object with default zero Id in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. What I get from user is a form submitted with certain fields e.g question body, title, tags. The tags text I receive is something like wpf,c#,mvc,java. I split the tags text by comma and then ask my context to see what tags I have in the database based on text. At that stage how can I create a complete tag w/o first retrieving the list of tags matching the user entered tags?

Comment: @QaiserIftikhar you need to to write a little javascript for this:)   React on keyup events of the input box and build the list of tags manually with javascript.

Comment: How can javascript help here? I can accept the question from webapi as well. In that case the api client will send me json/xml request which should contain the comma separated tags. All I need is a way of creating the tags which are not found in the db and attach the new/existing tags to the question. I have the solution but don't like it and need to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: You may want to avoid the tags.contains part, because it could lead to future performance problem. Better solution would be to identify tags with numeric ids instead of string values (the api client will send list of objects instead of comma separated list).

Comment: But api does not know the tags, so how can it sent me the id's? The tags are added as free text (separated by comma) on client side, on server side I need to work out if I already have the entered tags or not. The api only accepts a very limited number of tags (i-e max 10) so am not worried about performance.